# 301 or linking to domain

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect, backlinks, landing-page

I purchased a number of (oldish) domains, 2 or 3 of these domains have relatively good backlinks and according to MOZ (if that is worth anything) a goodish page rank.

These domains are currently empty, there is nothing on them, not even a landing page, I am hoping these domains can give my primary site a bit of a boost interms of link equity and backlink.

What are my best options here?

- Doing a 301 redirect from old domain to my primary domain
- Simply putting an index page on the domain with a link to my primary domain

Comment: Recommend that you read guides dated 2015 and on wards, because 301 empty domains regardless of how many backlinks is useless, and one page low quality sites are a one way ticket to Penguin land. Old domains for back links are only good if they are a. have relevant content, b. have decent content. c. have good Google standings. This is why people are now opting to purchase sites, not domains.

Comment: Simon is perfectly right! One way or another, we have answered this question many times here. Adding domains do nothing for you.